# Difference between javascript class declaration

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was trying to create a module for node.js and i noticed something. Example

```
function Example() {
     this.property = "something";

}

Example.prototype.run = function() {
     console.log('hello world')
}

module.exports = Example;
```

with this code it say's that there's no method run. I need it to declare like

```
Example.prototype.run = function run() {}
```

to work. Why is that happening ?

Comment: How are you trying to run it? It works perfectly well: `var Example = require('./example.js'); new Example().run();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work fine as long as you actually call the constructor and create an object which is how you've configured the Example code:

```
var Example = require("./example");
var item = new Example();
item.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the module and *instantiate* the Example class.

Example.js :

```
function Example() {
    this.property = "something";
}

Example.prototype.run = function() {
    console.log('hello world')
}

module.exports = Example;
```

main.js :

```
var Example = require("./Example.js");
var example = new Example();
example.run();
```

run:

```
$ node main.js
hello world
```